# What factors should be considered when deciding between a Flink aws cluster via docker or on an EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I read through the documentation for 1.7 on the process for AWS which has their EMR deployment as the recommended way (but sounds like that is because of ease of deployment). My ideal scenario would be to have a session cluster, mostly because I am most familiar with that and the cluster wouldn't have to be redeployed on code changes.

My biggest question revolve around if there are there performance pros/cons between a cluster set up with docker on an ec2 (please correct me if I am wrong about the EC2 part. Still getting up to speed with AWS) vs EMR. The data volume would be in the high end of hundreds of millions a day.

Thanks for any help in advance!